# How can I initialize a dictionary in python from a list of keys for each key to have the same initial value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values I want to use as keys and I want each key to have the same value

```
keys = ["red", "blue", "green"]

# final dictionary
d = {"red": 0, "blue: 0, "green": 0}
```

I am trying to use the `dict(keys, [0,0,0])` constructor but that does not work. I've also tried `dict((keys, [0,0,0]))`, however that does not work either.

From a tutorial post, I see that I could do `dict("red"=0, "blue"=0, "green"=0), but in the actual case I need this for I won't know how many keys I will have.

What would be a way to do this? Ideally, I would also like to avoid passing in an array of identical values for the same reason that I don't know how many keys I will have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `dict.fromkeys`

```py
keys = ["red", "blue", "green"]

output_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)

print(output_dict)
```

```
{'red': 0, 'blue': 0, 'green': 0}
```

**CAUTION:**

```py
keys = ["red", "blue", "green"]

value = [1,2,3]

output_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys, value)

print(output_dict) # {'red': [1, 2, 3], 'blue': [1, 2, 3], 'green': [1, 2, 3]}

output_dict['red'][0] = 77 # you think output should be {'red': [77, 2, 3], 'blue': [1, 2, 3], 'green': [1, 2, 3]}

print(output_dict) # actual output {'red': [77, 2, 3], 'blue': [77, 2, 3], 'green': [77, 2, 3]}
# see all 1s changed to 77
# because there is no 3 list for red, blue, green
# only one list is there and same is assigned to red, green, blue

# in this case use 
# output_dict = {k:value.copy() for k in keys}
```

Comment: Best and most appropriate answer here. Beware if you’re using a mutable object like a list though instead of `0`, then this probably won’t work as you think.

Comment: Yes, that is very true. There have been few questions in SO itself where people put list as value, then they were changing one value and surprisingly all values were getting changed. I hope @lllrnr101 will look into the comment section and be aware of that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the comments. Could you explain in which cases using a list would be a problem?

Comment: Check the caution. It can happen for any mutable data types

Answer (score 2):

[Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) are your friends if you want per-element processing.

```
>>> keys = ["red", "blue", "green"]
>>> {key:0 for key in keys}
{'red': 0, 'blue': 0, 'green': 0}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
keyList = []
d = {k:value for k in keyList}
```